# Перенос слов перед корнем

Tags: перенос

Прочитала в школьном справочнике такие правила переноса:
 - нельзя отрывать от корня первую согласную букву (от-крепить, но не отк-репить)
 - нельзя отрывать от приставки конечную букву, если корень также начинается с согласной (рас-тянуть, но не ра-стянуть)

Возникает вопрос: что делать, если корень начинается с гласной? Как переносить, например, "подоконник"? Можно ли так: по-доконник?

Выглядит как-то странно. Если это неверно, то зачем же во второй фразе упоминается согласная буква?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это верно. По-доконник - правильный вариант переноса.

**Дополняю, потому что комментарии кончились...**.
 У Лопатина:

Вводные замечания. При расположении текста на странице (печатной, машинописной, рукописной) нередки случаи несовпадения конца строки со знаком пробела, из-за чего возникает необходимость разрыва буквенной цепочки, соответствующей слову. Такой разрыв обозначается знаком переноса (черточкой). Чтобы уменьшить неудобства, возникающие в связи с этим при чтении текста, вводятся правила переноса. В основу правил переноса положен слоговой принцип. Однако в ряде случаев учитывается и членение слова на значимые части.

§ 211. Не разрешается оставлять на строке или переносить в следующую строку одну букву. Напр., нельзя переносить: а-кация, акаци-я.

§ 212. Не разрешается оставлять на строке или переносить в следующую строку буквенную цепочку, не содержащую гласной буквы. Напр., нельзя переносить: cm-вол, вс-лед, цен-тр, тре-ст.

§ 213. Не разрешается отделять от предшествующей согласной буквы ъ и ь. Правильные переносы: отъ-езд, коль-цо, перь-ями, буль-он; не допускаются переносы: от-ъезд, кол-ьцо, пер-ьями, бул-ьон.

§ 214. Не разрешается отделять переносом букву й от предшествующей гласной буквы. Правильные переносы: рай-он, вой-на, стой-кий; не допускаются переносы: ра-йон, во-йна, сто-йкий.

§ 215. Не разрешается отделять гласную букву от предшествующей согласной буквы, если эта согласная — не последняя буква приставки. Правильные переносы: чу-дак, ка-мин, до-мой, ша-лун, ба-лык, пле-нэром, пле-тень, по-лёт, хо-мяк, би-рюк; не допускаются переносы: чуд-ак, кам-ин, бир-юк и т. п.

Если же согласной заканчивается приставка, а за ней следует гласная буква, перенос в соответствии с этим правилом возможен, но возможен и такой перенос, который соответствует членению слова на значимые части. Допускаются, напр., не только переносы бе-заварийный и беза-варийный, ра-зоружить и разо-ружить, по-дучить и поду-чить, но и без-аварий-ный, раз-оружить, под-учить.

Примечание. Если после приставки, кончающейся согласной буквой, следует буква ы, то допускается только перенос после гласной буквы: ра-зыграть или разы-грать.

§ 216. Разбиваются переносом удвоенные согласные, входящие в корень или образующие стык корня и суффикса, напр.: жуж-жать, мас-са, кон-ный, весен-ний, рус-ский. Не допускаются переносы: жу-жжать, ма-сса, ко-нный, весе-нний, ру-сский или русс-кий.

Однако после приставок удвоенные согласные при переносе могут не разбиваться; возможны, напр., переносы со-жжённый, по-ссориться и сож-жённый, пос-сориться.

§ 217. Группа неодинаковых согласных букв в середине слова, входящих в корень или образующих стык корня и суффикса, может быть разбита переносом любым образом, напр.: се-стра, сес-тра и сест-ра; це-нтральный, цен-тральный и цент-рольный; ро-ждение и рож-дение; де-тство, дет-ство, детс-тво и детст-во; шу-мный и шум-ный.

Если же в группе согласных часть принадлежит приставке или если вся группа начинает вторую часть приставочного слова, предпочтительно учитывать членение слова на значимые части. Предпочтительные переносы: под-бить, под-бросить, при-слать, от-странить. Допустимые переносы: по-дбить, подб-росить; прис-лать; отс-транить и отст-ранить.

§ 218. На стыке частей сложного или сложносокращенного слова возможны только такие переносы, которые соответствуют членению слова на значимые части, напр.: авто-прицеп, ле-со-степъ, ново-введение, двух-атомный, трёх-граммовый, пя-ти-граммовый, спец-одежда, спец-хран, сан-узел, гос-имущест-во, дет-ясли.

§ 219. Не подлежат переносу: а) аббревиатуры, пишущиеся (полностью или частично) прописными буквами, напр.: ДОСААФ, ЮНЕСКО, КамАЗ; б) графические сокращения, напр.: б-ка, ж.-д., р/сч; в) написания, представляющие собой сочетания цифр и окончаний слов, напр.: 20-й, 365-й.

Comment: А под-оконник - неправильный? Или так тоже можно?

Comment: Нельзя. Общий принцип - слово переносится по слогам. А вы нарушили слоговое деление. По-до-кон-ник.

Comment: Тогда надо углубляться в процесс деления на слоги. Является ли он однозначным? И чем определяется: только буквенным, или также морфемным составом слова?  

Ведь слоги типа "под" и "о" имеют право на существование.  
я не всегда точно знаю, где проводить границу, особенно если подряд идут несколько согласных.  

[Здесь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/3778/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) я прочитала, что законы переноса в последнее время стали более демократичными.

Comment: А можно перенести подо-конник? Судя по [этой ссылке](http://www.orfo.ru/tutorial/html/spel_hyph.htm) - нельзя.  

Этого правила, правда, нет в материалах за 5 класс (мы с сыном их сейчас повторяем). Может, такое правило встретится ему в будущем?

Comment: Можно! У Лопатина те же примеры приводятся как допустимые: беза-варийный

Comment: И вообще: неправильный перенос исправляется, но на оценку не влияет. В каком классе Ваш сын?

Comment: Пока пятый закончил. Но я уже задумываюсь о ГИА/ЕГЭ. Туда эти вопросы входят?  

Вот еще одна ссылка на [Грамота.Ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=perenos). Тут вообще допускаются варианты. Или этот сайт неавторитетный?  

Господи, кому же верить? :-((

Comment: В разные теории слогоделения углубляться не надо. Я думаю. в учебнике Вашего сына "правильные правила"

Answer (score 1):

Современные правила переноса (по факту использования профессиональными корректорами) не столь строгие. Школьный справочник изрядно устарел.

Если ориентироваться на Лопатина, то императивными являются лишь параграфы 211-215 и 219. Всё остальное (216-218) де-факто носит рекомендательный характер. Мало того, что изложение довольно запутанное, не сразу поймёшь, так они ещё и не покрывают всех случаев. Кроме того, делить слово на морфемы - это тоже не такое простое дело, не стоит его ставить во главу угла при формулировке требований к переносам. Тем более, когда текст на 99% оформляется программно, где уж компьютер таким тонкостям обучить.

Перенос по-доконник безусловно правилен.